# Access last array element in swig template

Tags: javascript, twig, swig-template

I have an array:

```
product.paths = [ text: 'hello', text: 'world' ]
```

How do I access the last element in a swig template tag?

This element:

```
{{ product.paths[1].text }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with swig but twig has last filter which gives the last element of an array.  http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/last.html

Have you tried something like the below?

```
{{ product.paths|last }}
```

EDIT:
I've just looked at the filters list for swig on the github project and it does have a last filter so the above should work. https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/master/lib/filters.js

EDIT2:
If it was a multidimensional array you could try setting a variable to the last element, and then do any further actions on it.

```
{% set last_element = product.paths|last %}
{{ last_element.text }}
```

Comment: I initially tried that but I can't figure out how to use that and get the text element - i.e. [product.paths|last].text (which doesn't work)

Comment: According to the twig filter docs it should return the value of a key:value array so it should just give you the value of 'text' if your array example is accurate. If not you could try setting a variable to equal the last element, see edit2.

Comment: Yes i am doing the variable thing now - I guess I would like to find out how to encase the filter expression inside of something so that it is recognized as an array - parens and curlies break and square brackets yield nothing - just might not be possible.